# get sliced results after sql execution

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I am developing a **Rails** app.

after I execute a **sql** command like following:

```
sql="select * from some_tbl;"
rslt = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(sql)
```

how can I get sliced results from `rslt`?

I mean for example, if the `rslt.size` is 200, I would like to get 20 results start from the 5th one (which like the array operation `arr[5,20]`), how to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to convert `rslt` to Array:

```
...
rslt.to_a[5,20]
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't need to fetch all the instances of the table, you can do:

```
Model.offset(5).limit(20)
```

You should read that, it will probably help: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#limit-and-offset

Answer (score 0):

The object returned from `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute` is in fact an `Array` which means you can use `rslt[5,20]` to obtain the 20 results starting at the 6th element.

I'd also like to point out that you can use `find_in_batches` which is an API provided by [ActiveRecord](http://railsapi.com/doc/v2.3.2/classes/ActiveRecord/Batches/ClassMethods.html).

The example given on the API page is:

```
Person.where("age > 21").find_in_batches do |group|
  sleep(50) # Make sure it doesn't get too crowded in there!
  group.each { |person| person.party_all_night! }
end
```

EDIT: sorry it didn't work for you. direct from my rails (3.0.10) console

```
ruby-1.8.7-p299 :006 > sql = "select * from domains"
 => "select * from domains" 
ruby-1.8.7-p299 :007 > ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(sql).class
 => Array 
ruby-1.8.7-p299 :008 > ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(sql).length
 => 18 
ruby-1.8.7-p299 :010 > ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(sql)[5,20].length
 => 13
```

Comment: Hi, I am using Rail v2.3 . I tried rslt[5,20] which is failed that's why I post this question. I don't know why you say rslt[5,20] is working... THe error I got is something like "the active record result is got, but [] expect an array", obviously it is not working.

Comment: @Mellon i reported that it worked because it did work for me. using ruby 1.8.7p299 and rails 3.0.10, i was able to get the results i reported above. good luck.

Answer (score -1):

You dont need to use sql in rails you use `ActiveRecord` to create, read, update and delete entries in the database. You should read the beginners guides from http://guides.rubyonrails.org/ especially the `Model` section will be interresting for you because its about dealing with the datbase!

Comment: Hi, I know this. I have a special situation to use it. Thank you but your answer did not related to what I am asking

Comment: Sorry but your question suggested that you are trying to do some simple sql with raw sql instead of active record.